# Running function twice and saving the output for comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, for-loop, cypress

I have a function that is part of a test that is running at the beginning of the test and then again at the end. During the test, things are happening in the background that will make the output different at the end. I need to compare both runs at the end. Here is my attempt

```
const func = () => {
        const nums = num.getAll() 
        let values = []
        for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
            const arr = nums[i].temps
            arr.forEach((element) => {
                values.push(element.aggregate)
            })
        }
     return values
}
```

While debugging I can see this function working properly. This is roughly my test.

```
it('test', function () {

     const firstTimeRunning = func()
     cy.log(firstTimeRunning) // gives blank output
     ..............
     .............. //logic that changes the output of the function
     const secondTimeRunning = func()
     if(firstTimeRunning != secondTimeRunning){
          ............ //this gives undefined != undefined
  }
}
```

Lastly, `console.log(func())` does not give any output, however, I can see `return values []` while debugging with the correct information. How can I properly do this?

Comment: Is `num.getAll()` async? That aside, this compares array *references*, not *contents*.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some `cy.get()` or other commands inside `num.getAll()`, in which case you will need to add `.then()` to await the command results.

Broadly speaking,

```js
it('test', function () {

  func().then(result1 => {

    cy.log(result1)

     .............. //logic that changes the output of the function

     func().then(result2 => {

       if (result1 !== result2) {
         ...
       }
     })
  })
})
```

---

**With aliases**

```js
it('test', function () {

  func().as('result1')

  .............. //logic that changes the output of the function

  func().as('result2')

  cy.get('@result1').then(result1 => {
    cy.get('@result2').then(result2 => {
  
       if (result1 !== result2) {
         ...
       }
    })
  })
})
```

---

The above shows you the pattern to use in your test - you can't use `cy.log()` synchronously unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not able to wrap the two calls like that because of the in-between logic

Comment: alias is undefined. Somehow the return statement in the function isn't actually returning when calling the function

Comment: Yes, you will have to modify `func` but I'd need to see what `num.getAll()` does and probably the HTML to advise on that.

Comment: num.getAll() is simply getting another array getting me close to the array I really need to iterate through. But the function clearly in the debugger `Return value: Array(5) 0: 1, 1:42, 2:76, 3:12, 4:90`

Comment: I'm doubtful that's the whole story - `nums[i].temps` would give you an error.